# How to solve this tennis-probability problem in SIMPLE terms?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

I must admit probability has always confused me; therefore, my intuition for it is weak. Could someone please help me understand and solve this problem by explaining clearly, simply, and with detail?

In certain sports, like tennis, winning a game requires a lead of two points. That is, if the score is tied you have to score
two points in a row to win. A point is scored every play. Suppose your probability of scoring the next point is always p.
Then your opponent’s probability of scoring the next points is always 1 −p.

1. What is the probability that you will win the next two points?
   2.What is the probability that you and your opponent splits the next two points, i.e. that neither of you wins both
   points.
2. What probability that you and your opponent split the next two points but you win the two after that?
3. What is the probability that either you win the next two points or split the next two and win the two after that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that points are decided at random and independent (i.e. tossing a coin - which I appreciate is not how tennis is played), then the chance of you winning n points in a row is $p^n$, so the chance of you winning the next two points is $p^2$.

Similarly the chances that you and your opponent split the two points is the same as you win the first point, and then they win the second - or they win the first point, and then you win the second. Since real numbers commute under multiplication, this is just $2*p*q$, where $q=1-p$.

Now the probability that we split the next two points, but I win the two after that is the first two answers multiplied $p^2*(2*p*q)=2*p^3*q$. I.e. the chances of the second event (we share the points) times by the the chances of the first event (I win two in a row).

Finally, the last part is a little trickier. The first two questions relied upon an 'and' question, and if the events are independent (i.e. you getting a point doesn't change the chances of you getting another point) we can work out 'and' statements by multiplying. That's how we got $p^2$ and our other answers. We write this as:

Suppose A and B are events, we denote the probability of A happening as $P(A)$. We do the same for event B. If A and B don't affect each other, we know that that $P(A$ and $B)=P(A)*P(B)$. Using a formula which I'll discuss in a bit, we know that:

$P(A$ or $B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A$ and $B)$

To answer your final questions, A is the event I win the next two points, and B is the event that we split the points and I win the the two after that. Using our formula we have that the chances of this:

$p^2+(2*p^3*q)$. I.e if the probability is $1/2$ the answers to your questions are:

1. 1/4 and 1/2
2. 1/8
3. 3/8
   Note you can't have A and B since you can't win the first two points and share the first two points, so $P(A$ and $B)=0$ for these two events.

Now, where did I get the the $P(A$ or $B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A$ and $B)$? It's easiest to picture a venn diagram with everything that counts as event A in one circle, and everything that counts as event B in another. The chance that either happens if called the union, and it's everything included the the bit where they overlap  - how much is this? Well it's all of A plus all of B, minus the overlap. This is called the inclusion exclusion principle. Useful links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle